# is there a way to ignore checksum error?

Tags: installation, checksums

I have downloaded installer of Mathematica from it's website but checksum does not match and i can't install it. Is there any way to ignore checksum and install it anyway?

Comment: While you are free to ignore any errors, the installer is not. It, most likely, not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

If the checksum is not right, your file is corrupted or someone tampered with it. Just download it again. There may be some workaround for this but this would mean that you would either install a broken software or a malware.